# How to use Affdex SDK in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, affdex-sdk

We are trying to use the iOS Affdex SDK with a bridging header (in Swift). Can you please help us how to go about this process. Also how can we display up emojis based on the SDK (agin using Swift).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some links to help you with Objective-C to Swift naming conventions:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html

I’ve attached a simple view controller class which shows how to use our SDK in Swift. Hopefully this will help you.

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController, AFDXDetectorDelegate {

    var detector : AFDXDetector? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // create the detector
        detector = AFDXDetector(delegate:self, usingCamera:AFDX_CAMERA_FRONT, maximumFaces:1)
        detector?.setDetectEmojis(true)
        detector!.start()
    }

    func detectorDidStartDetectingFace(face : AFDXFace) {
        // handle new face
    }

    func detectorDidStopDetectingFace(face : AFDXFace) {
        // handle loss of existing face
    }

    func detector(detector : AFDXDetector, hasResults : NSMutableDictionary?, forImage : UIImage, atTime : NSTimeInterval) {
        // handle processed and unprocessed images here
        if hasResults != nil {
            // handle processed image in this block of code

            // enumrate the dictionary of faces
            for (_, face) in hasResults! {
                // for each face, get the rage score and print it
                let emoji : AFDXEmoji = face.emojis
                let rageScore = emoji.rage
                print(rageScore)
            }                
        } else {
            // handle unprocessed image in this block of code
        }
    }
```

Comment: `public init!(delegate: AFDXDetectorDelegate!, using camera: AFDXCameraType, maximumFaces: UInt)` is deperecated as of Swift 3, any alternatives?